# python socket multiclients sending,

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I got a problem python socket server send data only to one client which was added last.
I tried use `sendto(data, addr)` but it doesn't work all the time.
The server is supposed to work as a remote command line in windows.
The server communicates with one client and it doesn't have any problem with it, but with more it just doesn't work. Python version: 3.9
Maybe someone will be able to help me?
Here I put the code:

SERVER

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "192.168.0.117"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
server.settimeout(2)
clients = []


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    clients.append(addr)
    print(clients)
    connected = True
    while connected:
        command = input("[SERVER] => ")
        for client in clients:
            conn.sendto(command.encode(FORMAT), client)
            print(f"Sending data: {command} to {client}")
    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = server.accept()
            thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
            thread.start()
        except socket.timeout:
            continue
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

And here is client:

```
import socket
import os
import sys
HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = "192.168.0.117"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


# it doesn't work yet
def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    

def command_bot(command):
    if len(command) > 1:
        try:
            comm = ""
            for x in command:
                comm += x + " "
            os.system(comm)
            print(comm)
        except os.error as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(1)

    
def start():
    while True:
        command = str(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)+" ")
        comm = []
        y = ""
        for x in command:
            if x != " ":
                y += x
            else:
                comm.append(y)
                y = ""
        if comm[-1] == "":
            comm = comm[:-1]
        command_bot(comm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Comment: I have no idea what `sendto()` does on a SOCK_STREAM socket but it doesn't do what you think it does. I would think it would raise an exception.

Comment: Each client connecting is going to create a `handle_client` thread that asks for interactive input.  How do you expect that to work with multiple clients?

Comment: this should work because sendto sends data to the specified address, in this case to each of the "clients" list

Comment: Mark Tolonen, I expect it to be possible to send data to a specific client, or to a group of clients, or to all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server code is creating a thread for each client which is getting input from the user and iterating over all the client connections, not just the new client connection. You may want to consider having one thread iterate over the clients and add the client connection in the main loop.

Try this updated server code which works with multiple client connections:

```python
def handle_client():
    while True:
        command = input("[SERVER] => ")
        for client in list(clients):
            conn = client[0]
            try:
                conn.sendall(command.encode(FORMAT))
                print(f"Sending data: {command} to {client[1]}")
            except Exception as ex:
                print ("ERROR:", ex)
                print("remove client:", client[1])
                clients.remove(client)
                try:
                    conn.close()
                except:
                    pass

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    threading.Thread(target=handle_client).start()
    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = server.accept()
            print("client:", addr)
            clients.append((conn, addr))
        except socket.timeout:
            continue
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

hi again if someone will be want send data to only one client here a put the code
I think it looks amateurish but it works.
Enter command: `sendto -c <client's address ip> <command>` example: **sendto -c 192.168.0.117 start [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**

```
def handle_client():
    while True:
        command = input("[SERVER] => ")
        command = command.split()
        for client in list(clients):
            try:
                if len(command) > 1:
                    if len(command) > 3:
                        if client[1] == (command[2], client[1][1]) and command[0] == "sendto" and command[1] == "-c":
                            c = command[3:]
                            comm = ""
                            for x in c:
                                comm += x + " "
                            client[0].sendall(comm.encode(FORMAT))
                            print(f"Sending data: '{comm}' to {client[1]}")
                            continue
                if len(command) > 0 and command[0] != "sendto":
                    comm = ""
                    for x in command:
                        comm += x + " "
                    client[0].sendall(comm.encode(FORMAT))
                    print(f"Sending data: '{comm}' to {client[1]}")

            except Exception as ex:
                print("ERROR:", ex)
                print("remove client:", client[1])
                clients.remove(client)
```